# How do I view the size of npm packages?

Tags: npm, package, size

When I search for packages on NPM, I would like to see package sizes (in KB or MB, etc). NPM doesn’t seem to show this information.

How can I determine how much bloat an NPM package will add to my project?

---

Update 2020 (copied from @styfle answer)

The "Unpacked Size" (basically Publish Size) is available on the npmjs.com website along with "Total Files". However, this is not recursive meaning that npm install will likely be much bigger because a single package likely depends on many packages (thus Package Phobia is still relevant).

There is also a pending RFC for a feature which prints this information from the CLI.

Comment: some modules depend on other packages and you may be already downloaded them with other module .

Answer (score 328, accepted):

What you probably want to measure is the impact a package has if you were to add it to your app bundle. Most of the other answers will  estimate the size of the source files only, which maybe inaccurate due to inline comments, long var names etc.

There is a small utility I made that'll tell you the min + gzipped size of the package **after** it gets into your bundle.

https://bundlephobia.com

Comment: Beautiful UI!  Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.  Takes forever on super large packages though.

Comment: This link: [`https://cost-of-modules.herokuapp.com`](https://cost-of-modules.herokuapp.com) now directs to [`https://bundlephobia.com`](https://.bundlephobia.com)

A very useful tool btw.

Comment: How should the result of bundlephobia be interrupted? For example, for https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=geoip-lite@1.3.6, it is showing a size of 31kb (minified), but according to cost-of-modules (128.09M), and download-size (36MiB).

Comment: When I run my bundle through I get an unexpected error too many requests, how do I fix that that? @ShubhamKanodia Thanks!

Comment: They have also rolled out a beta version of a `package.json` scanner!

Comment: this is very great and accurate! I hope it exists as an extension in VScode, Import Cost is not very accurate sometimes

Comment: This is extremely elegant.  Exactly what I was looking for--thank you!

Comment: @ZeyadShaban they had made it an extension at your time of writing... looks like it's still flown under the radar. It requires package.json at root of workspace, but it looks like it works. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=crewsycrews.bundlephobia-support

Comment: At first glance, this seems like a useful tool.  But it really only shows minified sizes.

Answer (score 98):

Take a look at this [cost-of-modules](https://github.com/siddharthkp/cost-of-modules) project. It's an npm package that will list the size of a package and number of children.

Installation:
`npm install -g cost-of-modules`

Usage:
Run `cost-of-modules` in the directory you are working in.

[image]

Comment: A bit overkill, it need to reinstall all your modules before the computation. But does the job.

Comment: don't use this package - it creates an artifact folder called nodemodules.bak which creates ugly side effects

Comment: install or reinstall will always overkill, Am also looking for the options where nothing can be installed back.

Comment: i would prefer to go with @bkk https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-module-stats

Comment: what ugly side effects this package create?

Comment: Use flag --no-install
`npx cost-of-modules --no-install`

Comment: Great, I ran the command and now my project doesn't work

Comment: @KrystianMateusiak
Is also messing around with the loc files.

Comment: I ran this module, it creates 8756 files in my node_modules! This package does it without any warning notification. Destructive and rubbish.

Answer (score 60):

I created Package Phobia early this year with the hope to get the package size information into npmjs.com and also track package bloat over time.

https://packagephobia.com

[image: img]

This is designed to measure disk space after you run `npm install` for server-side dependencies like `express` or dev dependencies like `jest`.

You can read more about this tool and other similar tools in the readme here: https://github.com/styfle/packagephobia

---

*Update 2020*

The "Unpacked Size" (basically Publish Size) is available on the npmjs.com website along with "Total Files". However, this is not recursive meaning that `npm install` will likely be much bigger because a single package likely depends on many packages (thus Package Phobia is still relevant).

[image]

There is also a pending [RFC](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/1) for a feature which prints this information from the CLI.

Comment: This is great, but why do its results differ so markedly from bundlephobia? e.g. compare the results for lodash.lowerfirst

Comment: @DanyalAytekin Because they're measuring different things. Short answer: if you are looking at a front-end package use BundlePhobia. If you are looking at a back-end package use PackagePhobia. There are more details in [the readme](https://github.com/styfle/packagephobia/blob/master/README.md#how-is-this-different) if you are interested.

Comment: This is excellent. Can you please do this to calculate the total of the sizes

Comment: Great tool, but it should probably offer better feedback about the package it's measuring - something to verify you're comparing the right one, like a description.

Answer (score 36):

In case you are using webpack as your module bundler have a look at:

- [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)
- [webpack-bundle-size-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-size-analyzer)

I definitely recommend the first option. It shows size in interactive treemap. This helps you to find the size of package in your bundled file.

[image: Webpack Bundle Analyzer]

The other answers in this post show you size of the project, but you might not be using all parts of the project, for example with tree shaking.  Other approaches then might not show you accurate size.

Comment: Marvelous! In general, the first one may be added as a plugin to a Webpack configuration or passed in Laravel Mix. At the plugin Webpack build time (after the bundling/compilation), it starts a web server on `127.0.0.1:8888` with the interactive map. Related: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer#size-definitions

Answer (score 31):

I've created a tool, [npm download size](https://arve0.github.io/npm-download-size/), which inspects tarball size for a given npm package, including all tarballs in the dependency tree. This gives you an idea of the cost (install time, disk space, runtime resources, security audit, ...) of adding the dependency up front.

[image: download size of webpack]

In image above, *Tarball size* is tar.gz of package, and *Total size* is size of all tarballs. The tool is pretty basic, but it does what it says.

A [cli tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-size) is also available. You can install it like this:

```
npm i -g download-size
```

And use it like this:

```
$ download-size request
request@2.83.0: 1.08 MiB
```

The source code is available on Github: [api](https://github.com/arve0/npm-download-size-api), [cli tool](https://github.com/arve0/npm-download-size-cli) and [web client](https://github.com/arve0/npm-download-size).

Comment: Doesn't seem to calculate sizes for any dependencies... ie. when I ran it it just listed the package I asked. When I actually installed, more than 1000 packages were installed... taking up more than 10 times the amount of space reported.

Comment: Is it perhaps missing recursive dependencies?

Comment: It does resolve packages recursive, but report tar.gz size, not unpacked size. The web-ui also shows number of recursive dependencies. What package did you test on?

Comment: Just the cli. Maybe if it showed a package count... or specified the .tar.gz ....

Answer (score 16):

Try to use **package-size**.

```
npx package-size vue,vue-router,vuex react,react-dom,react-router,redux
```

https://github.com/egoist/package-size
[image: package-size npm]

Answer (score 7):

Before publishing the npm package, You can check the size of the package using the following command.

**`npm publish --dry-run`**

I have attached the result of my npm package.

[image]

Comment: useful—would also be nice if it could sort by size

Answer (score 6):

If you use Visual Studio Code, you could use an extension called [Import Cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost).

> This extension will display inline in the editor the size of the imported package. The extension utilizes webpack with babili-webpack-plugin in order to detect the imported size.

Comment: Also available for WebStorm.

Comment: This extension doesn't work for all the packages. It shows Calculating... and then suddenly vanishes even after changing the timeout value to a very large number

Answer (score 6):

[howfat](https://github.com/megahertz/howfat) is one more tool which can show total package size:

```sh
npx howfat jasmine
```

[image: screensot]

Answer (score 3):

You could check out [npm-module-stats](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-module-stats). It is an npm module that gets the size of an npm module and its dependencies without installing or downloading the module.

Usage:

```
var stats = require("npm-module-stats");

stats.getStats("glob").then((stack) => {

  let dependencies = Object.keys(stack);
  let totalSize = dependencies.reduce((result, key, index) => {
    return result + stack[key].size;
  }, 0);

  console.log('Total Size in Bytes ', totalSize);
  console.log('Total Dependencies ', dependencies.length-1);

}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

It might seem a little verbose but it solves the problem you described appropriately.

Comment: What about 2nd level deps?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer https://github.com/aholachek/bundle-wizard all the way since it was released.

- It works on deployed sites: `npx bundle-wizard reddit.com`
- It works on your local project:

  For multi-page apps/sites adjust the last line with the path you want to check.

  ```
  npm run build
  npx serve -s build
  npx bundle-wizard localhost:5000/
  ```

The interactive view is really helpful in discovering what's where.

Answer (score 2):

A "quick & dirty" way is to use curl and [wzrd.in](https://wzrd.in/) to quickly download the minified package and then grep the file size:

`curl -i https://wzrd.in/standalone/axios@latest | grep Content-Length`

The download is minified but not gzipped, but you get a good idea of the relative size of packages when you compare two or more of them.

Comment: Well, use another service like [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com) then. Example: `curl -i https://unpkg.com/axios@0.16.1/dist/axios.min.js | grep Content-Length`

Answer (score 1):

In order to check the impact of different packages on your bundle. You can check out [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer).

Install:

```
npm install -g source-map-explorer
```

Usage:

```
source-map-explorer bundle.min.js
source-map-explorer bundle.min.js bundle.min.js.map
source-map-explorer bundle.min.js*
source-map-explorer *.js
```

This will open up a visualization of how space is used in your minified bundle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created [bundlejs](https://bundlejs.com) for this exact reason. Bundlejs was designed to be a fast and always accessible online bundler that can treeshake, analyze the bundle, minify, gzip & brotli the bundle, give the compressed size, and also return the fully bundled code, you can check it out at https://bundlejs.com.

The source code is available on GitHub at  https://github.com/okikio/bundlejs

[image: image of bundlejs bundling & minifying react]

[image: image of the final bundle for react]

However, if you're goal is to just check what the npm install size for packages, I highly recommend https://packagephobia.com. I didn't create packagephobia but it's a high quality tool that covers the other niche when it comes to checking js package sizes