# how can i check the size of npm packages before download?

Tags: github, npm

Is there any online utility or tool that helps me to find out the exact size of node packages before downloading or installing them or is there any way to check the size of git repositories so that i can check the size of the package from its git repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view the size of npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642008/how-do-i-view-the-size-of-npm-packages)

Answer (score 6):

I've created a tool that does this. It's called [npm-download-size](https://arve0.github.io/npm-download-size/). A [cli version](https://github.com/arve0/npm-download-size-cli) is also available.

Just type a package name and Go!:

[image: npm download size start page]

Here is webpack analyzed:

[image: download size of webpack]

The cli tool can be installed with:

```
npm i -g download-size
```

And used like this:

```
$ download-size lodash
lodash@4.17.4: 303.39 KiB
```

Here is an [asciinema demo](https://asciinema.org/a/GqCnDlllrI0YtJgc7BkxisCla) of the cli tool.