# How can I get bundlephobia to show different sizes in export analysis?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs, terser

So I'm using [bundlephobia](https://bundlephobia.com) to audit the bundle size of my packages. Bundlephobia has a section called "Export Analysis" that gives you the bundle size of the individual exports.

[image: export analysis]

So each of these functions in this bundle are pure functions so, unless I'm missing something, I think these should show a smaller size for each function but all of them (except the re-exported one) have the same size.

I tried:

- Adding `"sideEffects": false"` to my `package.json`
- Marking every function with `#__PURE__`

I'm using rollup and [this is my rollup config](https://github.com/ricokahler/color/blob/826f96ecf767d85aeb0d53ebc5969f48b8fd4544/rollup.config.js):

```
// rollup.config.js
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

const extensions = ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'];

export default [
  {
    input: './src/index.ts',
    plugins: [
      resolve({
        extensions,
      }),
      babel({
        babelrc: false,
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
        babelHelpers: 'bundled',
        extensions,
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      file: 'dist/index.js',
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'parseToRgba',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  },
  {
    input: './src/index.ts',
    plugins: [
      resolve({
        extensions,
        modulesOnly: true,
      }),
      babel({
        babelrc: false,
        presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
        babelHelpers: 'runtime',
        extensions,
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      file: 'dist/index.esm.js',
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    external: ['@ricokahler/parse-to-rgba'],
  },
];
```

Nothin.

How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe @shubham-kanodia knows, the author of Bundlephobia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43166167 (I'm not sure if tagging him works though :) )