# Meaning of `unpacked size` in npm and how can I reduce it?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Recently I published [a humble package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chicago) in npm.
After then, I found `unpacked size` item in npm website.

I thought my package is small and simple. but `unpacked size` is nearly 2mb
Shocked, I tried [Bundlephobia](https://bundlephobia.com/package/react-chicago@0.1.0-a) and It said my package is 12.2kb

And now I'm so confused, what `unpackes size` in npm really means?

---

I found a [STO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642008/how-do-i-view-the-size-of-npm-packages) related about this. but I can't understand early.

Answer (score 5):

'unpacked size' is the size of all the stuff you're downloading when installing an npm package. the code in this package will not be minified, it will include comments for the IDE and most likely type declarations.

'bundle size' is the size of the npm package after being bundled using a module bundler like webpack, so it's the actual size of the package in a production build.

so - for development you have to download this 3mb package, but after building your app the user will only have to download extra 12kb of code

Comment: then how can I reduce my unpacked size?? I'm afraid the big size will be disadvantage to users